# MM/yy Date parse issue - Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor

Tags: android, kotlin, date

I am trying to convert my date (MM/yy) in String format to LocalDate. However, I get a `DateTimeParseException`.

The detailed error is -

> j$.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12/34' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=12, Year=2034},ISO of type j$.time.format.Parsed

My code is as following -

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yy")

 val currentDate = LocalDate.now().format(formatter)
 val expiryDate = LocalDate.parse(validityDate, formatter)

 val period = Period.between(expiryDate, LocalDate.parse(currentDate, formatter))
 val months = period.months
```

The exception occurs during this code execution -

`val expiryDate = LocalDate.parse(validityDate, formatter)`

The value of `validityDate` is "12/34".

I can't figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you didn't specify the day in month, so `LocalDate` cannot parse the date.

```kotlin
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy")
val validityDate = "01/12/34"

val currentDate = LocalDate.now().format(formatter)
val expiryDate = LocalDate.parse(validityDate, formatter)

val period = Period.between(expiryDate, LocalDate.parse(currentDate, formatter))
val months = period.months
```

I tested it with the above code and successfully parse the `validityDate`.